# 'TileInterfaceTest.UserControl1.label1 is inacessible due to its protection level'

Tags: c#, class, user-controls

For my A2 computing project I have decided to program a timetable software piece using C#. I have been trying to program a system in which clicking a panel in Form1 will change the text within label1 which is on UserControl1 which has been placed upon panel 2. At first this seemed like a trivial task but it would seem I was punished for my ignorance. As stated in the title when using the solution I thought would work I was told that label1 is 'inacessible due to its protection level', frankly this has baffled me. Anyway, here's the code. I'm quite new to C# and StackOverflow so please be tolerant of any stupid errors.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TileInterFaceTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void panel1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void panel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserControl1.label1.Text = "Text";
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: The label's *Modifiers* property as visible in the Properties Window  matters.  It defaults to *Private*.  Which produces this error, you can't access private members.

Answer (score 0):

label1 is a private member in UserControl1, so you can't get to access it outside that class.

possible solutions:

1 . in `UserControl1` create public property

```
public string Title
{
    get {return label1.Text; }
    set {label1.Text = value; }
}
```

then in your form set that property

```
private void panel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
     UserControl1.Title = "Text";
}
```

2 . the following code should also work

```
 UserControl1.Controls["label1"].Text = "Text";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But after trying both solutions twice I don't receive any syntax errors however nothing happens when I click the panel. I feel I may have forgotten to assign an object to a class etc.

Comment: @ShreddedWheat, try set chechpoint inside `panel1_Click` method, then run the application and click panel1. does checkpoint get hit?

Comment: After placing a tracepoint inside panel1_click and running the program, it seems that clicking the panel does not hit the tracepoint.

Comment: @ShreddedWheat, at least you can try set title in constructor : `InitializeComponent(); UserControl1.Title = "Text";` to check whether title property is working at all. also  UserControl1.Title should be visible in form-designer in properties window, if you are working in Visual Studio